Is it legal to write a book about debates that I've participated in?
I was online and I didn't really see anything regarding this, I thought that if I made an informative book including debates that I've had, it would help out other debaters and speakers by providing actual examples. Is it possible to make a book about this? Also, do I need permission from the other side to write about these debates that would include what they said and what I said?
Since, I coudn't find anything wither or not it was legal to publish what I said and what they said in a debate. Basically, if I were to include what they said, could I get sued or would there be any legal issues.

Leaving aside the ethics of publishing something without the consent of your co-authors, maybe that's more a question for https://law.stackexchange.com (though you should generalize your question if you decide to post it there). It may vary between jurisdictions, though I suspect it would be very illegal in most places. You're not the unique author, and a debate usually contains much more substance than a trivial discussion, so it would be hard to argue that this isn't covered by intellectual property laws.

You might find some relevant info for the US here: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-do-co-authors-rights-to-a-manuscript-work. For other countries, it may be completely different, so don't assume things work like in the US, depending on your location, where you intend to publish, and on the circumstances of these debates.

Whether you can legally reproduce debates in a book will depend on the following:

Will you reproduce them verbatim, e.g. from recordings?
Are the topics or opinions so specific that the participants of the debate might be recognizable?
Were the debates an organized event?
Were the participants experts in the topic and did they participate in their professional capacity?
Did the participants prepare for the event?

If you answer yes to one or more of these questions, the speeches are probably "works" in the sense of copyright law and you must not reproduce them without permission.
If the debates were spontanous discussions among friends about the things that everyone talks about all the time, you reproduce the debates from memory, and no speaker is recognizable, you can publish that book without infringing on anyone's rights.

Most of the debates I took part in are either in debate apps and platforms and online social media, or online platforms.

@T.S Then you will have to consult the Terms of Service of those platforms and see what rights you granted them when you participated and under what rights the contributions of you and the others are published. The ToS should tell you whether you still have the copyright of your contributions and whether you may republish the contributions of the other participants.
